# Simple recipes web app with Redux

Tags: ecmascript-6, react.js, sass, redux

I have completed a coding challenge from Free Code Camp. [The challenge](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/zipline-build-a-recipe-box)'s user stories are as follows:

> - I can create recipes that have names and ingredients.
> - I can see an index view where the names of all the recipes are visible.
> - I can click into any of those recipes to view it.
> - I can edit these recipes.
> - I can delete these recipes.
> - All new recipes I add are saved in my browser's local storage. If I refresh the page, these recipes will still be there.

Also, a rule was to use React and SASS (The FCC founder said that SCSS is acceptable).

This was my first attempt at using Redux. As a result, some things in the app are experimental. For example, the reducer works well and returns a new state each time - but I'm sure the code here could be better written.

Also, in the `RecipeList` component, I found myself confused at how I should use the component's state, or draw data from the Redux store. Some thoughts on this are most welcome.

As was recommended to me on a different code review, I used the [BEM](https://en.bem.info/) pattern for my SCSS.

I used [Vex](http://github.hubspot.com/vex/docs/welcome/) for the modals. This resulted in some pretty ugly code. For example, html tags within a string (which I think looks really confusing in the vicinity of JSX). But the functionality is fine, I believe. Would React-Bootstrap be a better option in this case?

[Here is a link to a Codepen of the app](http://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/full/dGRqyR/)

**Javascript:**

```
const initial = () => {
   let recipesInit = {
      recipes: [
         {id: 1, title: 'Pao de queijo', ings: '100ml milk, 100ml vegetable oil, Pinch of salt, 250g tapioca flour, 125g parmesan or vegetarian alternative, grated, 1 free-range egg'},
         {id: 2, title: 'Monastery Gyuvetch', ings: '2 lbs beef, 4 tomatoes, chopped, 1/2 lbs mushrooms, 1 cup rice, 1 onion, chopped, 15 olives, whole, a bunch of parsley, 2 tbsp vegetable oil, 1 tbsp butter, 1 tbsp sugar, 2 1/2 cups beef stock, black pepper, paprika and salt'},
         {id: 3, title: 'Hobaktteok', ings: '½ cup cooked butternut squash, ¼ cup honey, 2 tablespoon freshly squeezed lemon, 2 cups rice flour (frozen rice flour sold at a Korean grocery store or make your own), lemon zest from 1 lemon, 1 tablespoon water, ¼ teaspoon salt,2 tablespoons sugar'}
      ],
      currentlySelected: 1
   };

   var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('recipesObject');
   let parsedRetrievedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);

   const noRecipesInLocalStorage = parsedRetrievedObject === null || parsedRetrievedObject.recipes.length == 0;

   if(noRecipesInLocalStorage) {
      return recipesInit;
   } else {
      return parsedRetrievedObject;
   }
};

// Reducer
const recipeReducer = (state = initial(), action) => {
   let newState = {};
   let newRecipes = [];

   switch (action.type) {
   case 'ADD_RECIPE':
      console.log(action);
      newRecipes = [...state.recipes, action];
      newState = Object.assign({}, state, {recipes: newRecipes});
      localStorage.setItem('recipesObject', JSON.stringify(newState));
      return newState;

   case 'DELETE_RECIPE':
      console.log(action);
      newRecipes = [
         ...state.recipes.slice(0, action.id),
         ...state.recipes.slice(action.id + 1)
      ];
      newState = Object.assign({}, state, {recipes: newRecipes});
      localStorage.setItem('recipesObject', JSON.stringify(newState));
      return newState;

   case 'CHANGE_SELECTED_RECIPE':
      console.log(action);
      return Object.assign({}, state, {currentlySelected: action.currentlySelected});

   case 'EDIT_RECIPE':
      console.log(action);
      newRecipes = [
         ...state.recipes.slice(0, action.id),
         action,
         ...state.recipes.slice(action.id + 1)
      ];
      newState = Object.assign({}, state, {recipes: newRecipes} );
      localStorage.setItem('recipesObject', JSON.stringify(newState));
      return newState;

   default:
      return state;

   }
};

const {createStore} = Redux;
const store = createStore(recipeReducer);

const RecipeList = React.createClass({
   getInitialState(){
      return {
         currentlySelected: store.getState().currentlySelected
      };
   },

   editPrompt() {
      let current = store.getState().recipes[this.state.currentlySelected];

      vex.close();

      vex.dialog.open({
         message: 'Edit Recipe',
         input: `<input name="editTitle" type="text" value="${current.title}" />
               <textarea name="editIngs" rows="7">${current.ings}</textarea>`,
         buttons: [
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
               text: 'Cancel',
               click: () => vex.close()
            }),
            $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.YES, {
               text: 'OK'
            })
         ],
         callback: data => {
            if(data){
               store.dispatch({
                  type: 'EDIT_RECIPE',
                  id: this.state.currentlySelected,
                  title: data.editTitle,
                  ings: data.editIngs
               });
            }
         }
      });
   },

   infoPrompt(i) {
      store.dispatch({
         type: 'CHANGE_SELECTED_RECIPE',
         currentlySelected: i
      });

      this.setState({currentlySelected: i}, () => {
         let current = store.getState().recipes[this.state.currentlySelected];

         vex.dialog.open({
            message: `<h1>${current.title}</h1> \n ${current.ings}`,
            input: '',
            buttons: [
               $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.YES, {
                  text: 'Cancel'
               }), $.extend({}, vex.dialog.buttons.NO, {
                  text: 'Edit',
                  click: () => this.editPrompt()
               })
            ]
         });
      });
   },

   render(){
      return (
         <ul className="col-xs-12">{
            this.props.recipes.map((recipe, i) => {
               return (<li className="jumbotron list__jumbo row" key={i}>
                  <div>
                     <span className="list__close-button col-xs-1" onClick={ () => store.dispatch({id: i, type: 'DELETE_RECIPE'}) }>&times;</span>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                     <span className="list__title col-xs-11" onClick={this.infoPrompt.bind(this, i)}>{recipe.title}</span>
                  </div>
               </li>);
            })
         }</ul>
      );
   }
});

const Header = (props) => {
   return (
      <div className="header-main">
         <h5 className="header__mainTitle"><a href="http://github.com/alanbuchanan">My Tasty Recipes</a></h5>
         <div className="header__addButton-container">
            <a onClick={props.save} target="_blank"><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>
         </div>
      </div>
   );
};

const RecipeBox = React.createClass({
   savePrompt() {
      vex.dialog.open({
         message: 'Add a Recipe',
         input: `<input name="userTitle" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
            <textarea name="userIngs" type="text" rows="7" placeholder="Ingredients/Cooking instructions"/>`,

         callback: data => {
            if(data) {
               store.dispatch({
                  type: 'ADD_RECIPE',
                  id: Date.now(),
                  title: data.userTitle,
                  ings: data.userIngs
               });
            }
         }
      });
   },

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <Header save={this.savePrompt}/>
            <RecipeList recipes={store.getState().recipes}/>
         </div>
      );
   }
});

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<RecipeBox />, document.getElementById('root'));
store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

**SCSS:**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script);
$bg-color: #eee;
$header-title-color: #d4d4d4 !important;
$add-button-color: #118DF0;
$jumbo-bg-color: #69938e;
$jumbo-font-color: #fff;
$close-btn-color: #cccccc;
$header-main-title-font: 'Chewy', cursive;
$list-title-font: 'Bad Script', cursive;

@mixin main-transition() {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .12s ease-in-out !important;
    -moz-transition: opacity .12s ease-in-out !important;
    -ms-transition: opacity .12s ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: opacity .12s ease-in-out !important;
    transition: opacity .12s ease-in-out !important;
    &:hover {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
}

body {
    background-color: $bg-color;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover, &:active, &:visited, &:link {
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}

.header-main {
    height: 60px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.header__mainTitle {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    font-family: $header-main-title-font;
    color: $header-title-color;
    font-size: 23px;
}
.header__addButton-container {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}

.btn-circle-sm {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.65;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.glyphicon {
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 38px;
    color: $add-button-color;
    @include main-transition();

}

.list__jumbo {
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: $jumbo-bg-color !important;
    color: $jumbo-font-color !important;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    @include main-transition();
}

.list__title {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: $list-title-font;
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 100%
}

.list__close-button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: $close-btn-color;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px){
    .container {
        width: 750px
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see some Redux conventions misconceptions:

1. The `reducer` purpose is to change the state, I see that you also copy state to localStorage.
2. You should use **actionCreators** to save data in localStorage. In actionCreator, you save data and then - dispatch action to reducer.
3. Any of the React components with Redux don't need to have state. You should pass all callbacks and properties via `props`. And use the Redux's `connect` function to the root component.
4. You don't need to use `store.getState()` in the React component views. You should read your data or state values from `props`.
5. Not fully defined the state of application (now I see only data in state): you have selected/not-selected recipe - this is state, you have modal opened/closed - this is also state.